# select two calculations with one query in active record

Tags: activerecord

In SQL I would do a `"select count(*), min(price) from products"`. What is the best way to do this with one query in active records?

Right now I have to do two queries, which doesn't feel right.

```
result_count = Product.where(filter_string).count
result_min = Product.where(filter_string).minimum(:price)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the string in a `select` method like this:

```
result_stats = Product.select("count(*) as product_count, min(price) as price_min").where(filter_string)[0]
result_stats["product_count"] # => 123
result_stats["price_min"] # => 12.35
```

The limitation here is that this will initialize `Product` objects with only those fields accessible (in this case only 1 object since there's no `group by` clause). In this case, it's not really an issue, but something worth knowing if you get an error when you try to access relations.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields